# String value sent to series.data, expected Number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, highcharts

I'm having an error when publishing my rails app to Heroku with Highcharts ([error 14](http://highcharts.com/errors/14)). In development it all works fine, and the values aren't transformed into strings.

Basically, when my view is loaded on Heroku, i get the following code :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
    $(function () {
        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'visualization',
                    plotBackgroundColor: null,
                    plotBorderWidth: null,
                    plotShadow: false
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Receipts by Gender'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    pie: {
                        allowPointSelect: true,
                        cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        showInLegend: true
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    name: 'Receipts by gender',
                    data: [["M", "432854518.0"]]
                }]
            });
        });

    });
    </script>
```

If we look at series.data, we will see  [["M", "432854518.0"]], and here we have the problem.  The value on the right should be a float or at least an integer.

My controller :

```
    @pie_gender_total = Receipt.group_by_gender_pie(current_user, :total)
    @pie_gender = @pie_gender_total
```

My view :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
$(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        ...
            series: [{
                ...
                data: <%=raw @pie_gender %>
            }]
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

And my model method :

```
def self.group_by_gender_pie(user, dim, begin_date=nil, end_date=nil)
    arr=[]
    self.group_by_gender(user).each do |item| arr.push([item.gender, dim == :count ? item.number_of_receipts : item.total]) end
    arr
  end
```

Any ideas on why the same solution works in development, but not so for my heroku environment ? And workarounds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i found that the problem could be tracked down to the model.

Here is the solution (basically convert the numbers to float) :

```
 def self.group_by_gender_pie(user, dim, begin_date=nil, end_date=nil)
    arr=[]
    self.group_by_gender(user).each do |item| arr.push([item.gender, dim == :count ? item.number_of_receipts.to_f : item.total.to_f]) end
    arr
  end
```

I still don't understand why the different behaviour between development and heroku though.